# Python: "Cannot find root dir" when doing help('modules')

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm pretty new to python. When I try to list all the python modules with the `help('modules')` command, I get this as response: "Cannot find root dir"

It listed them just fine a couple of days ago, I'm not sure what I did to break it. I did try to install another module before this, so that might be it.

I have no idea how to fix it and google didn't help much either.

Answer (score 0):

Type `help()` into the Python REPL and press Enter. When the prompt changes to `help>` then type `modules`.

Comment: Didn't help, I get the same message by doing this